# How to use TTF as font family in HTML

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts, truetype

Can someone please help? I'm trying to reference the magnum font (URL attached) to my HTML. I've tried to use the src:url("Fonts/Magnum.ttf") from where I uploaded it to my file manager and still no luck so trying with the below but it just isn't working.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url("/https://fontmeme.com/fonts/magnum-fakhrul-razi-font/")
  format('truetype'), 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: That url is not the link to the font itself, but a website where you have a link to download it. You should add it to your website file system.

Answer (score 7):

That url is not the link to the font, but a website where you have a link to download it.

You should place it into your website and then "describe" it in your CSS:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('path/to/your/font.ttf');
}
```

and then, wherever you want to style using this font, use `font-family: 'MyWebFont'`, notice that the `font-family` name must be the same as the one given above:

```css
.myStyle {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont'
}
```

Find more about `@font-face` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Answer (score 1):

After I had gone to this website https://fontmeme.com/fonts/magnum-fakhrul-razi-font/ and downloaded the font this worked for me. Note, I put the font into the same folder as my HTML file just for a test. You will probably want to put it in something called fonts/ or similar.

```
<style>
@font-face{
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url(magnum.ttf); 
}
div {
  font-family: MyWebFont,Courier;
}
</style>
<div>Some text</div>
```